Can a man with lower tapas unite/love a girl with higher tapas?
Can a man with lower Tapasya marry a girl with higher tapasya..or will the boy will be afraid to approach the girl?
There is an example of Tapati devi the daughter of Suryadev marrying King Samvarana(I dont know if King Samvarana had higher power than Tapati devi)..what is your your understanding?
Kindly quote examples..
